# If $A$ and $B$ approximate a pair of commuting operators, then do $A$ and $B$ approximately commute?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, operator-algebras, approximation-theory

Let $A,B,\tilde A,\tilde B$ be positive operators on a complex separable Hilbert space, and suppose
\begin{gather}
\|A\| = 1 \hspace{1cm} \|A-\tilde A\|\ll 1 \\
\|B\| = 1 \hspace{1cm} \|B-\tilde B\|\ll 1 \\
[\tilde A,\tilde B]=0.
\end{gather}
Does this imply $\big\|[A,B]\big\| \ll 1$? Surely the answer is yes, but how can we prove/quantify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does if the norm is sub-multiplicative, because then

$$
\begin{align}
\|[A, B]\| &= \|AB-BA\|\\
&= \|AB-A\tilde{B}+A\tilde{B}-BA\|\\
&\le\|A\|\|B-\tilde{B}\|+\|A\tilde{B}-BA\|\\
&= \|A\|\|B-\tilde{B}\|+\|A\tilde{B}-\tilde{A}\tilde{B}+\tilde{A}\tilde{B}-BA\|\\
&\le \|A\|\|B-\tilde{B}\|+\|A-\tilde{A}\|\|\tilde{B}\|+\|\tilde{A}\tilde{B}-BA\|\\
&= \|A\|\|B-\tilde{B}\|+\|A-\tilde{A}\|\|\tilde{B}\|+\|\tilde{B}\tilde{A}-BA\|\\
&= \|A\|\|B-\tilde{B}\|+\|A-\tilde{A}\|\|\tilde{B}\|+\|\tilde{B}\tilde{A}-\tilde{B}A+\tilde{B}A-BA\|\\
&\le \|A\|\|B-\tilde{B}\|+\|A-\tilde{A}\|\|\tilde{B}\|+\|\tilde{B}\|\|\tilde{A}-A\|+\|\tilde{B}-B\|\|A\|\\
&=2\|A\|\|B-\tilde{B}\|+2\|A-\tilde{A}\|\|\tilde{B}\|.
\end{align}
$$